# How can I change the label format of figures for my list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, numbering

I have a ToC with Chapters in roman numbers and sections/subsections/subsubsections in Arabic format.
When I insert a figure the default label is like this:
For chapter I: Figure: I.1, I.2, I.3, ... For chapterII: II.1, II.2, II.3...
I would like it to be all in Arabic as 1.1, 1.2,... and 2.1, 2.2...
I'm using this in the preamble:`\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}`  and `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}` so my ToC looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! what is the problem?  Please provide a small but complete document which produce your problem.

Comment: How about `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{......}`  to whatever you want?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I fixed it with: \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}

Comment: @Valeria: Can you write that up as an answer to your question and accept it? That way this question can be considered completed (or closed).

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved using

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
```